# How to change the focus highlight color used for when the user is navigating the screen using a physical keyboard?

Tags: android, accessibility

When an Android user connects a bluetooth keyboard to the device and navigates the screen using this keyboard there is this gray box around the element that is currently focused.

Is it possible to change the color of this "box"?

Thanks in advance!

edit: I found a solution. You can add this on your App theme

```
<item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/selected_item_focus</item>
```

Comment: I'm interested in this as well.  Have you found a solution?

Comment: add this on your app theme: